# The report server cannot process the report or shared dataset

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a problem when I deploy my report project to a remote ssrs with the shared datasource.
When I'm using the SQL Server data tool to "preview" my report, it's looks like have no problem. But when Y deply the project, this error message appear

> The report server cannot process the report or shared dataset. The shared data source 'DataSource1' for the report server or SharePoint site is not valid. Browse to the server or site and select a shared data source. (rsInvalidDataSourceReference)

---

noteworthy that the datasource it's pointing to the remote database

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If you are using a report server, then perform the following steps:

1. Be sure you're on a version of IE this will not work correctly in Chrome
2. Go to your report server
3. Click on **...** , on top-right of your report name
4. Click on 'Manage'
5. Click on 'Data Sources'
6. Make sure that **Connect to:** settings are pointing to the right places.

You would be amazed how many times this will happen because of a credentials issue or how the data source is setup. 
In the same case share data source will be in a different folder than the initial one. Maybe you will see a warning label.

Without more information about what kind of server you are using, this is all I can think of suggesting.

Comment: when i click on the report i just get a white screen - i don't see the properties on the left hand side. Any ideas why? Viewing this in Google Chrome.

Comment: this didn't help me. still looking for the solution

Comment: This didn't help me, either; in SQL Server Reporting Services, clicking the report name tries to run the report (eventually the error that this post is about appears); right-clicking it has a "Properties" item, but just a "General" tab with Protocol, Type, and Address (read-only info); right-clicking the down-arrow has no properties. OTOH, right-clicking the .rdl file in Solution Explorer does have a "Properties" but also no "Datasources" tab...

Comment: This worked for me - I had deleted the original dataset from the server, which I then replaced with the updated version to capture some changes I had made.  However, the Shared Dataset reference still referred to the (Now deleted) original dataset.  Once I replaced this the report worked as expected.

Comment: Oh man, thank you for this. Admin had to do a couple things on the report server, and the datasources got disconnected, I kept trying to re-deploy but that did not work, and to manually do these steps (used chrome however) and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to bulk update and fix the problem by updating the data source link using the T-SQL below.

```
 begin tran
update dbo.DataSource
set Link = c.ItemID 
from dbo.DataSource ds 
inner join dbo.Catalog c
on ds.Name = c.Name
and c.Type = 5
where ds.link is null

select ds.Link oldlink, c.ItemID 
from dbo.DataSource ds 
inner join dbo.Catalog c
on ds.Name = c.Name
and c.Type = 5
--where ds.link is null


select *
from dbo.DataSource ds 
where ds.link is null

rollback tran
-- commit tran
```

http://tsqlblog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/rsinvaliddatasourcereference-on.html

Comment: This worked for me, sort of. I had to change the `on ds.Name = c.Name` line, because my reports' data sources did not have the same name as the shared data source.

Answer (score 5):

I Tried this Solution :-

Deploy All Data Sources and reports to report server once again.

This solution solve my problem

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Initially I used a Datasourse that pointed to a local DB. When I create a remote ssrs and redply the project on server, I change manually the shared datasource.

Like I use a shared data source, every report has link to this shared datasource. The problem is that this link point to a old version of the datasource.

to solve the problem I refresh the link to the new datasource