# SSRS - Browse folders - what does it want?

Tags: ssrs-2012

For SQL Server 20212 (Sp1) 11.0. 3128 - I'm trying to pick a data source for a report (to fix error here: [The report server cannot process the report or shared dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126706/the-report-server-cannot-process-the-report-or-shared-dataset))   The report was creating in Visual Studio on a different enviornment.

On my SSRS Home page, I currently have the data source: 
[image]

But on this screen, I'm confused what it wants me to type in or click to pick that Intergation.rds data source.  I'm not sure what the "Home" folder/button does, it doesn't seem to change anything when I click it.  Should I be able to browse and pick the file, or what do I type in the location?  Or is the name "Integration.rds" in my report, and I just need to point to the folder it's in?

[image]

I moved report and .rds and .rdl to a folder called "EDI Reports". 
I'm starting to see how the folder structure works, but when I try to change it and click "Apply", I get this error too: 
The operation you are attempting on item '/EDI Reports' is not allowed for this item type. (rsWrongItemType)

I am able to get it to work if I use "a custom data source" and put in the connection string and select integrated security.

Answer (score 1):

The HOME button takes you to the main page, which is where you already were at, so it appears to not do anything.

Usually you would have a separate folder for Data Sources (and another for Datasets if you're using Shared Datasets).

You might also want to break up your reports into folders for each department or other category to make browsing easier. You click on the folders to navigate and click on report icons to go to the report.

If you move your dataset, you'll need to update the report's Dataset in the Dataset tab of the report properties (Manage) using the folder tree view.

When you try to MOVE a report, you should use the folder tree to select a folder. It will not create a new folder but instead give you the error.